# need a poison easy to get hands on undetectable in autopsy should appear victim had a heart attack

Tags: science-based

it must be undetectable in autopsy.
it must appear victim died of heart attack.
it can be administered via drink or food.

i am doing some research to prove a hypotheses made by a college.

Comment: Yeah I dont feel very comfortable with this question.

Comment: Salt, bacon, sugar...

Comment: @Demigan if they actually wanted to kill someone, they could just go ahead and stab them when no one sees... 44% of murderers are never captured.

Comment: @Vesrie sure, but a knife in the back is odd for a domestic accident, so they will try to find the murderer, and you just had to cross fingers to dont be part of 56%. A heart attack ? That happen every time. The odds to catch someone are way lower if they don't search anyone.

Comment: @Kepotx 1)get your victim to be outside at dark or even during the day in a crowd...2)stab them 3) run 4) profit. But yeah a heart attack makes it more subtle if you live with the victim.

Comment: Your answer is in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4uvQRTCdYA

Comment: @vesrie there is a large difference between stabbing someone and using an untraceable poison. The chance of being caught being one. The emotional impact on the murderer is another as its far easier to poison some drink or food than it is to violently stab someone to death. The chance of success is also increased as humans can be surprisingly tough when medical care is around. So yes I am uncomfortable with advocating an easy to obtain untraceable poison.

Comment: The rushed way in which the question seems to have been made makes me a bit worried, despite the justification in the end.

Comment: I am not answering this question. Partially as I don't have an answer, plus my background is combat.

Comment: Curiously, [worldbuilding.se] has been asked this question many times. We're happy to answer questions about poisons from the perspective of worldbuilding (what would constitute a poison given the following rules of biology? Given the following creature's biology and an earth-like environment, what would normally poison a human but not the creature?)... we generally avoid questions like "I need a poison to achieve X" or "I need an undetectable poison" because they're always about *plot.* (See [tour] and [help].) I'm surprised the dup wasn't closed.

Answer (score 5):

Cholesterol, inject it into a steak or any meat based meal so they don't notice the taste.

Wait a few weeks, if they already have high cholesterol like 200 mg/l, which is probable since that's the **LOW AVERAGE** in the united states, then it takes only a few days.

1/3 of the world population already dies because of heart problems caused by diet, the homicide will go unnoticed, they might not even autopsy them, and if they do..they will think they was killed by the sin of gula.

Answer (score 0):

Make them eat a lot of meals with no Fiber in them for a couple of days. They will not be able to use the bathroom so they will need laxatives, then get them drunk...laxatives and alcohol don't mix together.

Go in a trip together with half a tank of fuel and get stranded in the desert....they will die of **diarrhea** !